# Send Google Analytics events about lost Internet connection

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

In my application I have to send Google Analytics events about lost Internet connection. Obviously I can't do it at the moment when Internet connection is lost, because there is no connection to send request. But is there any queue mechanism or setting in Google Analytics script to send events when connection is restored?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for 
[Queue Time](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference)

> Used to collect offline / latent hits. The value represents the time delta (in milliseconds) between when the hit being reported occurred and the time the hit was sent. The value must be greater than or equal to 0. Values greater than four hours may lead to hits not being processed.

Example

> ga('set', 'queueTime', 560);

there is also the [The ga Command Queue Reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/command-queue-reference) but its going to depend on how you want to deal with it.

Comment: While Queue Time allows to specify an offset it is not by itself a queueing mechanism. It isl a necessary prerequisite to allow for queuing,  but the actual holding back of the request until network connection is restored still needs to be done from within the application.